# Expression Tree - Math.Max replacement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

When I use expression trees to replace a method, such as Math.Max, it looks like it successfully replaces it in the expression tree. But when I go to use it in Entity Framework, it throws an exception about not supporting Math.Max for Entity Framework. But I am explicitly replacing it.

Does anyone know why? And a way to fix the code?

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class CalculateDatabase
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var calcs = GetCalculateToAmounts(GetTestItems(), 0.5m).ToList();
        }

        public static IQueryable<Item> GetTestItems()
        {
            var items = new List<Item>();
            items.Add(new Item()
            {
                DoNotItem = true,
                ReductionAmount = 2,
                PreviousDiscountAmount = 3,
                CurrentDiscountAmount = 10,
                CurrentAmount = 100,
                PreviousAmount = 50,
                CurrentBillAmount = 75
            });

            return items.AsQueryable();
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public bool DoNotItem { get; set; }
            public decimal ReductionAmount { get; set; }
            public decimal PreviousDiscountAmount { get; set; }
            public decimal CurrentDiscountAmount { get; set; }
            public decimal CurrentAmount { get; set; }
            public decimal PreviousAmount { get; set; }
            public decimal CurrentBillAmount { get; set; }
        }

        public static IQueryable<CalculateToAmount> GetCalculateToAmounts(this IQueryable<Item> entityItems, decimal percentage)
        {
            return entityItems.Select(CalculateAmountExpression(percentage));
        }

        public class CalcType
        { }

        public class CalculateToAmount
        {
            public CalcType CalcType { get; set; }
            public Item Item { get; set; }
            public decimal ItemAmount1 { get; set; }
            public decimal ItemAmount2 { get; set; }
            public decimal ItemAmount3 { get; set; }
            public decimal Bonus { get; set; }
            public decimal Discounts { get; set;  }
            public decimal Total { get; set; }
        }

        private static Expression<Func<Item, CalculateToAmount>> CalculateAmountExpression(this decimal percentage)
        {
            Expression<Func<Item, CalculateToAmount>> lambda = item => new CalculateToAmount()
            {
                Item = item,

                Bonus = item.DoNotItem
                    ? 0 
                    : item.CurrentBillAmount * (1 - percentage) + item.ReductionAmount,
                Discounts = item.PreviousDiscountAmount + item.CurrentDiscountAmount,
                Total = Math.Max(item.CurrentAmount + item.PreviousAmount, item.CurrentBillAmount)
            };

            var test = MathModifier.Modify(lambda);
            return test;
        }

        public class MathModifier : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
            {
                var isMinMethod = node.Method.Name.Equals("Min", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                var isMaxMethod = node.Method.Name.Equals("Max", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

                if (!isMinMethod && !isMaxMethod)
                    return base.VisitMethodCall(node);

                var left = node.Arguments[0];
                var right = node.Arguments[1];

                var minMaxReplaceMethod =
                    isMinMethod
                        ? Expression.Condition(Expression.LessThan(left, right), left, right)
                        : Expression.Condition(Expression.GreaterThan(left, right), left, right);

                return minMaxReplaceMethod;
            }

            public static Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> Modify<TIn, TOut>(Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> expression)
            {
                var modifier = new MathModifier();
                return (Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>>)modifier.Visit(expression);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you call

```
var calcs = GetCalculateToAmounts(GetTestItems(), 0.5).ToList()
```

it will work. But if you replace the above GetTestItems() with an entity framework _dbContext.Items, it will not work.

To test this code, you would need to add Item structure to the EF project, make a migration, and push it into the database.

I wish I could make this less technical so this question could be answered by a wider variety of people. Hopefully the bounty is adequate for an the answer. If not, please pm me.

Comment: oh sorry - the very first line :( - what I don't see: the example does not use `Math.Max` at all - is it possible that this is inside `ToSpendExpression` ?

Comment: Good catch. Updated. I had to change some code so it doesn't match what I wrote for work. Yes. ToSpendExpression was the one that had Math.Max. I moved it to CalculateAmountExpression and changed it to evaluate this method instead. It used to evaluate both expressions.

Comment: There error itself is because EF6 can't convert a portion of the expression into SQL. Did you look at the `test` before it returns? Did it actually get replaced?

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns in your code.  What is `entityItem`? How is that initialized? What is `item`? Where is that initialized?  How are the rest of your entities defined? You're calling functions that you did not mention. Your code doesn't seem to correspond to the class definitions you did show.  You should provide all of that information if you expect to get an answer.

Comment: Updated. I agree I should. Struggling a bit converting code to not match work's code. Thanks for the help Jeff Mercado!

Comment: Eris, yes. I when I was debugging, I was able to navigate into the linq query and see that Math.Max had been replaced by IIF(item.CurrentAmount + item.PreviousAmount > item.CurrentBillAmount, item.CurrentAmount + item.PreviousAmount, item.CurrentBillAmount). But the exception says that Math.Max is not supported. Which I was unable to find any references to Math.Max when navigating into the returned IQueryable. The answer may be in what I am doing wrong? Or why replacing methods using expressions is not supported by EF?

Comment: @TamusJRoyce the code you posted has a lot of typos (prob copy paste errors)

Comment: I edited the code to make it compilable.

Comment: The other thing that would help is the exception information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am running *exactly* your provided code with EF 6. The entity `Item` named Table1. The code runs successfully, the relpacement of Math.Max is successfully done.

Tracing the SQL with SQL Profiler it generates and sends the following SQL against the database:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[DoNotItem] AS [DoNotItem], 
[Extent1].[ReductionAmount] AS [ReductionAmount], 
[Extent1].[PreviousDiscountAmount] AS [PreviousDiscountAmount], 
[Extent1].[CurrentDiscountAmount] AS [CurrentDiscountAmount], 
[Extent1].[CurrentAmount] AS [CurrentAmount], 
[Extent1].[PreviousAmount] AS [PreviousAmount], 
[Extent1].[CurrentBillAmount] AS [CurrentBillAmount], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[DoNotItem] = 1) THEN cast(0 as decimal(18)) ELSE ([Extent1].[CurrentBillAmount] * (cast(1 as decimal(18)) - @p__linq__0)) + [Extent1].[ReductionAmount] END AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[PreviousDiscountAmount] + [Extent1].[CurrentDiscountAmount] AS [C2], 
CASE WHEN (([Extent1].[CurrentAmount] + [Extent1].[PreviousAmount]) > [Extent1].[CurrentBillAmount]) THEN [Extent1].[CurrentAmount] + [Extent1].[PreviousAmount] ELSE [Extent1].[CurrentBillAmount] END AS [C3]
FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]',N'@p__linq__0 decimal(1,1)',@p__linq__0=0.5
```

Conclusion: The code you provided is working, the expression tree manipulation is working, your conditional logic in the tree is translated to a SQL CASE expression.

Possibly your EF test is not isolated carefully enough and the Max.Math related EF exception is coming from other part of the code and/or indirectly from a fired event, overload etc.

Answer (score -3):

Is there a reason you left this in `IQueryable` land? `IQueryable` land makes everything run on the database. If you move it to `IEnumerable` land, I think it should work fine:

```
    public static IEnumerable<CalculateToAmount> GetCalculateToAmounts(this IQueryable<Item> entityItems, decimal percentage)
    {
        var func = CalculateAmountExpression(percentage).Compile();
        return entityItems.AsEnumerable().Select(func);
    }
```

Comment: If he moves this to IEnumerable then he will query the zillion rows to the _client_, then apply his C# function in the _client_

Comment: There's no `Where` clause shown. What's the harm in that?

Comment: The where can be _added_ to before and after using this IQueriable to compose a new one.

Comment: If you do the `Where` before, then you'll be fine. If you do it after, then yes, you'll have a problem.

Comment: Good point/valid answer. In the original code I am using the Max function result in the where clause (down the chain after a few more calculations). That is why it is critical for me to do this on the SQL side.